# PostgreSQL replication to Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-replication, amazon-rds

Amazon recently introduced PostgreSQL support for their Amazon RDS service. I was wondering if this scenario could be possible:

- Setup a PostgreSQL instance on Amazon RDS
- Install PostgreSQL on my VPS
- Setup replication so that any changes I make on the DB in my VPS are automatically mirrored on the PostgreSQL instance on Amazon RDS

Is this possible? If yes, what would be the steps to achieve it?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/605460/102814, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61305/7788, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66372/7788, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=547192#547192

Answer (score 6):

Replication using trigger-based systems like Londiste and Bucardo into and out of RDS is [now supported as of Nov. 10th 2014](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=582787#582787), per a reply on that forum thread.

Announcement [here](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/10/amazon-rds-postgresql-read-replicas/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. SImilar functionality is available for MySQL RDS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

However, the closest for PostgreSQL RDS that I could find is: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Check on AWS Forum for better thoughts around this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa